# PHP redirect is not redirecting

Tags: php, html, redirect, header, http-headers

I've looked into all the posted questions and answers in this regard and I've tried them all yet nothing solved my problem.

I have a login.php page which contains a form as following:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="#">
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" placeholder="name" name="username" type="text" autofocus required></div>
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" placeholder="password" name="password" type="password" required></div>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```

I'm verifying the data in the same page however the header function to redirect the user to the next page is not working. and even with this simple PHP code still I'm not able to redirect the user:

```
<?php if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
header('Location: http://google.com');
exit();?>
```

Your help is appreciated

Comment: If *anything* is rendered to the browser before the `header()` function is called, then it will not work.  Failing that, are you ensuring  what the value of $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] is? You may not be passing your evaluation and therefore never calling the `header()` function.

Comment: You're missing a `}`.

Comment: `is not working` is **never** a sufficient error description.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace:

```
action="#"
```

with:

```
action=""
```

Comment: It's considered better practice to leave the attribute out, even though most browsers will interpret it the same way.

Comment: I tried this and I tried to place the header at the top of the page but still nothing is working I get redirect to the same page

Answer (score 0):

check if the verification works.Erase header('Location: http://google.com') and echo something.i suppose the problem is that you don't pass the validation and that's why header doesn't work.